# Linking a Drop down box to open information from another page in original page

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I'm looking to create a page which has a drop down box that when submitted will open information from another page which will load underneath the drop down box. I think I could do this with a div but I am new to writing code and have completely confused myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jquery pop up for that. It is easy to make stylish pop ups which will attracts users attention. Pls refer the link http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ .U can find the demo and code der. It is easy. Please have a look at der.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="">Select a Page</option>
   <option value="http://www.google.com">My Page</option>
</select>
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

You then need to use javascript to bind an onChange handler to your select box which updates the "src" attribute of the iframe

**Javascript** via JQuery:

```
$(function(){  

   $("#mySelect").change(function(){

      if($(this).val())
      {
          $("#myIframe").attr("src", $(this).val());
      }
      else
      {
         $("#myIframe").attr("src", null);
      }

   });

});
```

If you want to insert the xml/html/text from another page into the DOM of the current page, you'll want to use AJAX, I recommend looking at the jquery ajax docs to get started:

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)